# Client side form validation doesn't work

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

I created a `create_form` in the controller without adding submit button.

```
$createForm = $this->createForm(new SlideCreate(), $slide, array(
                'action' => $this->generateUrl('ws_admin_slide_create'),
                'method' => 'POST',
                'attr' => array(
                    'id' => 'create_form',
                    'class' => 'form-vertical'),)
            );
```

I use a link to submit my form

```
<a onclick="document.forms['create_form'].submit();" class="btn green">
```

The problem is that local validation of the form doesn't work(Client-Side).

Comment: when you inspect the rendred form ( on client side using browser inspector ) did you see required on inputs ?

Comment: Can you show the content of SlideCreate please ? thx.

Comment: You don't have 'required' option : http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html

Comment: If you add a submit button, is the client side validation working?